# RegExp. Разрешить только один разделитель в тексте при двух возможных вариантах

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Была задача запретить использовать два разделителя подряд при заполнении текстового поля в форме. При этом разделителем может служить как пробел, так и дефис.

Написал так:

```
^(?!.*\-$)(?!.*([\-\s])\1)(.)+$
```

И в таком случае, регулярное выражение не пропускает текст если поставить два дефиса или два пробела подряд, но пробел и дефис или дефис и пробел вместе - пропускает.

Как в данном выражении запретить использовать пробел и дефис вместе?

https://regex101.com/r/XKnAj0/2

Comment: А по-простому `^(([^ ]*)|([^-]*))$` не катит?

Comment: А, да, нельзя два подряд... ну доработать несложно. Там небось ещё нельзя разделитель в самом начале, в самом конце, и протчая...

Comment: Да, нельзя в начале и в конце тоже, но в моём варианте в конце и так не пропускает, а то, что начинаться должно с буквы проверяется в другом выражении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы тогда не просто так:

```
^(?!.*\-$)(?!.*[\-\s]{2})(.)+$
```

Comment: Да, вроде бы то, что надо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `([\-\s])\1` находит двойной дефис или пробельный символ, так как первый символ захватывается в подмаску №1, а обратная ссылка `\1` находит именно такой же символ.

Вам нужно просто повторить поиск дефиса либо пробельного символа, `[-\s][-\s]`, или `[-\s]{2}` или `([-\s])(?1)` (`(?1)` повторяет *шаблон* первой захватывающей подмаски, здесь использовать не советую, просто для иллюстрации возможностей библиотеки PCRE).

Используйте

```php
^(?!.*[-\s][-\s]).*[^-]$
^(?!.*[-\s]{2}).+$(?<!-)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/7T8p9k/1). Экранировать дефис в начальной позиции в символьных классах не требуется.

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*[-\s]{2})` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу справа от текущей позиции есть 0 и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше, а потом два пробельных символа или дефиса
- `.*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше
- `.+` - 1 и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше
- `[^-]` - любой символ кроме `-`
- `$` - конец строки
- `(?<!-)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу слева от текущей позиции есть `-`.